# Missing templates after switching a theme

Tags: theme, template

i have problem, i bought and installed template for my site but all of my extensions are not showing on the frontend (backend is like it should ), so this are the errors in system.log, please advice what is causing this :

> 2013-09-07T18:52:43+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template
>   file:frontend/base/default/template/mathieuf/eventscalendar/events.phtml
>   2013-09-07T18:52:51+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template
>   file:frontend/base/default/template/my_igallery/listx.phtml

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall move the templates of those extensions to either `base/default` theme or the theme you purchased. I recommend the `base/default` theme because it will will work in case you will change theme again.

Comment: Welcome to Magneto StackExchange.